# allow_url_open needs to be on

Tags: php

i need to change the configuration of php.ini on server side (parameter is allow_url_fopen) from off to on but i donot have access to the php.ini file and i want to do it through php code but i dont know wat to do how to do and where to paste that code(should i place it before the headers i am using for downloading the file???)

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($fileName));
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Type: application/download');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 

ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($finalFileName);
exit;
```

thanksss in advance

Comment: the php.ini file is parsed by the webserver/apache on runtime. if your host is not allowing the function or safe mode is on then you cant change it. im not sure what your code example has todo with allow_url_fopen if its local you may not need the function, have you thought about using curl to retrieve the file, most hosts allow curl

Comment: by default allow_url_fopen is on but if its off by the host then may be its prohibited, another solution is to put php.ini in your root directory and change as you want. i used it in one of my solution for some graphics and did work. Best of luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not recommended to use that option.
Instead you should use the curl library.

```
function getUrlContent($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,  FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Info about security of [link: allow_url_fopen](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/tests/allow_url_fopen.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a function named **[ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)** to set php ini values on the fly. But in your case it needs proper permission from your server to use this feature. You can contact your hosting provider.

The best solution is using **[cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)** as it is enabled by most of the servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ini_set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) to change the properties, and `ini_get()` to view them, try this out:

```
echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');

if (!ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
    ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);
}

echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');
```

you can also try [`.user.ini`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) to change it, it's like an .htaccess for php.ini but your sysAdmin can deny any of this stuff, so like the others said check out [`curl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here? If you're just trying to force download on a local link, use a file system path (as readfile('./filename.ext')) instead of an URL. If you have to force a download on a downloaded file, do as Soaica Mircea suggested and use CURL.

allow_url_fopen is set to off for a reason, as it can produce results that are hard to predict.